# is there a way to create a whitelabel chatbase reporting to clients that want to see engagement for their users on our chatbot

Tags: chatbase

We have clients who post over their users (name, email, etc.) we then invite them to our chatbots.

We have a few chatbots that we want to try chatbase analytics with. However I would like to somehow have client facing reporting using this platform.

Does chatbase allow you to embed reports into your own dashboard?

Answer (score 1):

I am Sean from Chatbase support.  We do not currently support embedded reports, however we have a few options for workarounds.

1. Create a Chatbase bot (individual api key) for each client and invite them as [collaborators](https://chatbase.com/documentation/collaborators).  They can have the option of accessing the full suite of Chatbase reports from within the console, or you can provide deeplinks to individual reports from within your logged in dashboard experience.  The one caveat is that the client must be logged into their google account to be added as a collaborator and view the reports.
2. Take snapshots of the client's reports from the Chatbase console and display them as an image, or .pdf within your dashboard.

Comment: 5 years later and still no progress... furthermore, today I cant even find this "invite Collaborator" feature you mentioned